# Can I have multiple themes and desktops?

Tags: 18.04, unity, gnome, themes

Can I have a switch or a selection to switch between desktops and themes and name them.
And then select with the name?
For example I want to have some changes on desktop some settings and theme and call it "windows look"
And set another desktop and theme and name it: "pearl os"
And whenever I Want I select pearl or windows
Is it possible?

Comment: The only way that I am aware of to do something like this is to setup a VM and run it in a different desktop / workspace.  Of course, this is a waste of system resources, but as far as I know all Desktop Environments will only support one running theme at a time but some will allow for different wallpapers per desktop / workspace.

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me what you exactly want. Desktop environments indeed run one theme at a time, although with a little hacking one could create hotkeys or a menu system that allow to change quickly to another theme. That, however, will be independent of the desktop. Whatever desktop will always be themed according to the current theme.